# Expanding/collapsing a WPF Expander

Tags: wpf, expander

How to expand/collapse a WPF Expander in code? I need to do it in order to initialize a control in it.

Comment: Don't see why you need to expand...to initialize a control in it? If that control has it's Name property set you can easily refer to it in code without expanding the expander that holds the control you want to initialize.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `IsExpanded` property, set it to true for making the content visible:

```
myExpander.IsExpanded = true;
```

Set it to false to collapse the expander.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set `IsExpanded` property, but I prefer to use [`VisualStateManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and do such UI changes using  [`VisualStateManager.GoToState`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/VisualStateManagerNavbar.aspx).